# AngularJS Bind to Service variables vs service functions?

Tags: angularjs, service, 2-way-object-databinding

As an angularJS newbie, I am puzzled by the fact I have to bind to a function returned from the service to update the view, not the data itself,  I couldn't find any official document explaining this, Does anyone know why?

[JSFiddle Code Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Stongpa/6TKUL/5/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
binding to a function works!
    <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="tempLog.returnBuffer()"></p>
    <br><br>
       bind to the service variable: Doesn't work, why?
      <p>log={{tempLog.buffer}}</p>
        <br><br>
    bind to scope var instead of service var, still doesn't work
    <p>log={{logBuffer}}</p>
   bind to a scope var which points to the service Function, works!
            <p>log={{pLogFunc()}}</p>
    <button ng-click="addText('more')">Trace</button><br>
</div>
```

JS code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('myLog', function() {
    var internalBuffer = "";
    return {
        buffer:internalBuffer,
        trace:function(input){
                internalBuffer = internalBuffer + "<br>" +input;
                buff = input;
            },
        returnBuffer:function(){
            return internalBuffer;
        }
    }
});


function MyCtrl($scope, myLog){
    $scope.tempLog = myLog;
    $scope.logBuffer = myLog.buffer;
    $scope.pLogFunc = myLog.returnBuffer;
    myLog.trace("aaa");

    $scope.addText = function(str){
        myLog.trace(str)
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you forget the paranthesis (`{{tempLog.buffer()}}`)?

Comment: No, that is not the reason, the real problem is what is pointed out below by ryeballar, that the buffer variable returned by the service is not bound to the internalBuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an AngularJS binding problem, this is just how javascript works. 
In your service:

1 `buffer` is assigned to a primitive variable `internalBuffer`.

2 `trace()` accepts a parameter that changes the `internalBuffer` primitive

3 `returnBuffer()` returns the `internalBuffer` primitive

Since `trace()` changes the `internalBuffer` primitive, any binding to `buffer` does not affect the changes in the `internalBuffer`, furthermore, `returnBuffer()` returns the value of the `internalBuffer` so naturally the changes you made with the `trace()` function affects the return value of the `returnBuffer()` function.

Any of these suggestions may work on your end:

**[1]** If you want to bind from the `buffer` property of your `myLog` service, then change your `trace()` function to something like this:

```
trace:function(input){
  this.buffer = this.buffer + "<br>" +input;
}
```

**[2]** You may disregard the `buffer` property and solely use the `returnBuffer()` if you`don't want to expose your`internalBuffer`and only use the`trace()`to have access in changing the`internalBuffer`

**[3]** You can use both, the `buffer` property provides access to another buffer format while the `internalBuffer` holds all the private buffers / format / or anything else that you may not want to expose to the users of the service. Just be sure to update the `buffer` in your `trace()` function by using `this` as well.

Comment: I see, the buffer variable was only initialized once when the service is created, there is no binding between buffer and internalBuffer. (that is where I was mistaken). Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find this answer useful, you may mark this as the accepted answer.